# Using data from one file to create two appended lists to a new file

Tags: python, list, file, boolean, append

I am trying to take data from one file and create two lists which are both written to a new file. One of the lists contains names 6 characters or less and the second list contains a list with names that do not contain "a" or "e." I have the code done that will form both lists, I have tried them both separately and they work but, I cannot make them both append to a new list at the same time. Whichever list I do first will be the only one that gets appended to the new file. Any help would be much appreciated!

## Code

```
main_file = open("words.txt", "r")

#loops to find lists
lists = open('test.txt')
lists.read()
with open("test.txt", "a") as lists:
    for names in main_file:
        if len(names) <= 6:
            lists.write(names)
    line = True
    for line in main_file: 
        if "a" in line or "e" in line or "A" in line:
            line = False
        else:
            lists.write(line)
```

## Both lists need to be appended to a new and the SAME file

Comment: `main_file` is a cursor into the file and after the first loop is at the end of the file. To reset the cursor to the beginning of the file do `main_file.seek(0)` between the 2 loops. Alternatively, you can use `itertools.tee()` to create 2 duplicate streams. Or move both conditions into a single loop.

Comment: I've tried to move both of the conditions into a single loop but, when I do it just mixes the lists and I need them separate. Sorry, I am just beginning in programming so, I do not know too much.

Comment: the main_file.seek(0) did the trick! Except now I need to figure out how to separate the end word of the first list and the first word of the second list instead of them making one big word.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your qn correctly

```
import re
l1 = []
l2 = []
lists = open('test.txt','w')
with open('words.txt') as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        if len(line) <= 6:
            l1.append(line) 
        if not re.search(r'a|e', line):
            l2.append(line) 
lists.write('\n'.join( l1+l2 ) )
lists.close()
```